# Help with a relation to Congruences Modulo 5?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, congruences

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding some questions pertaining to Relations and Functions. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following congruences practice question:

```
   Let Z5 be the relation of congruence modulo 5. If 1 ≤ m, n ≤ 5, we define
    the product of two classes as [m][n] = [mn].
    Explain why [3][4] = [2].
```

Would [3][4] = [2] because 12 modulo 5 would leave a remainder of 2? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The reason you gave is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You are both right and straight to the point.